Reward and Penalty Design in reinforcement learning
I hope you're all doing well.
I am currently working on a reinforcement learning problem to solve an optimization problem in wireless networks and I'm having troubles with designing the reward and penalty functions.
Since the optimization problem we are trying to solve is a constrained one, wee need to penalize the agent whenever the constraints are violated. In the mean time, we try to maximize some objective function. So the value of the objective function must be given as a reward. Hence, the total reward (r_tot) would be the summation of the objective function (r) and the penalty (p) introduced due to the violation of constraints.
r_tot = r + p

However, this approach does not seem to be working well. It seems that the penalty value is ignored by the agent and it moves towards maximizing the (r) part of the reward signal. I'm assuming that this might happen due to different scales of (r) and (p). If the (r) and (p) part are not of the same scale, could this hinder the learning process?
By the way, we are using DDQN as our learning algorithm.

Are you sure you want to add penalty as your total reward instead of subtraction? And of course different scales of r and p can hinder the learning process, usually you can just introduce a scaling factor λ such as r_tot = r - λp. Also have you tried masking out invalid actions during the update() step? DDQN can zero out the Q-values for infeasible actions in the target computation.

Thanks. I have assumed that the penalty is always negative and hence, I added this negative value to the total reward.
In my case, there is no invalid action. All actions are valid but not all of them are equally good.

Did you program the DDQN by yourself or are you using a library? Also what is your state and action size? If possible, I propose downsizing your state and action size and testing it on a generic Q learning algorithm. That way, you'll be able to better understand your problem formulation.
